# Problems with create policy of update

Tags: postgresql

I want to use row level security to create a policy for update, tb.idx never could update to less than 2 if cls = 'great2':

```
 create table tb (
 idx integer,
 cls text);
create role user1;
grant all on tb to user1;
......
create policy up_p on tb for update
using(true)
with check (idx >2 and cls='great2');

output:
set role user1;
select * from tb; 
update tb set idx=1 cls='great2'
```

There are two problems:

1. when using `select * from tb`, it shows an empty table.
2. it allows update with idx=1 cls='great2'.

Answer (score 0):

> *it shows an empty table.*

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createpolicy.html)

> If row-level security is enabled for a table, but no applicable policies exist, a “default deny” policy is assumed, so that no rows will be visible or updatable.

So you need to create a policy that allows selecting:

```
create policy tb_select on tb
  for select
  using (true);
```

---

> *it allows update with idx=1 cls='great2'.*

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createpolicy.html)

> Existing table rows are checked against the expression specified in USING, while new rows that would be created via INSERT or UPDATE are checked against the expression specified in WITH CHECK

As you created the policy with `using (true)` that means all rows can be updated.

So you need:

```
create policy up_p on tb 
  for update
  using (idx > 2 and cls='great2');
```

Assuming there *is* a row with `(1, 'great2')` the following update would not update anything:

```
update stuff.tb 
  set cls = 'great2'
where idx = 1;
```

---

Note, that for the policy to actually be active you also need:

```
alter table tb enable row level security;
```

---

However, if you simply want to ensure that values for `idx` are always greater than 2 for rows with `cls = 'great2'`, a check constraint might be the better option:

```
create table tb 
(
   idx integer,
   cls text,
   constraint check_idx check ( (idx > 2 and cls = 'great2') or (cls <> 'great2'))
);

insert into tb 
values 
  (10, 'great2'), 
  (1, 'foo');
```

Now running:

```
update tb 
  set idx = 1
where idx = 10
```

results in:

```
ERROR: new row for relation "tb" violates check constraint "check_idx"
  Detail: Failing row contains (1, great2).
```

the same happens if you change the `cls` value for a row with `idx <= 2`

```
update tb
  set cls = 'great2'
where idx = 1;
```

Comment: thx! in my application, it also includes session variables. when I input set role user_p; set my.idx=2; set my.cls='great2'; I can select the tb table and output is not empty, since I have another policy for select, but when I input update with update policy above, it always shows update 0.